# how to protect request information from 3rd party android apps using python

Tags: android, python

how to protect request information from 3rd party android apps using server side.
Hello,
anybody can help, how to identify 3rd party android apps and we protect access from 3rd party

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you will be using a REST-based setup you might want to look into using ssl certificates and use https for verification and signal protection.

For a simpler solution, use a pre-shared-key and put it in the header of the request.

With that said your setup will only be as safe as your key management. Encryption and information security is **hard**.

Good luck!